# Manage complex UI with hiding/showing windows without losing scope/control

Tags: layout, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, states

With angular js, How can I manage an complex view layout that allows the hiding and showing of windows (and so on.) I need to do so without loosing any state or scope while reopening windows if the same url-path will be used. This is like showing a list of items, and opening each in a window parallel to the others. With angular and routes, the previous scope will be destroyed.

```
  (#/itemlist -> #/itemlist/item/1 and #/itemlist/item/2)
```

- One item opens multiple components (two windows; please move them around) with the same state, manged by the angular ui states.
- Each state has its own controller and each controller has its own scope.
- Scope inheritance can be designed later in an extended prototype, but should be independent of the view hierarchy.
- Controller and views will be destroyed by scope destruction or if all views are destroyed the controller and scope must be also destroyed (not completely implemented yet.)
- If a route is recalled and a scope exists the correlated view(s) will be reactivated.

The idea is to use two services that manage/stores the controllers and, via scope, the associated views. To shadow the management of both components, a generic controller `$stateProvider` is used to resolve the controller / view injection:

```
$stateProvider
.state({
    name : 'item',
    url: '/item/:id',
    views:{
        'genericCtrl' : {
            resolve : {
                views : function() { return ['TestView', 'TestView']; },
                ctrl  : function() { return  'TestCtrl' ; }
            },
            controller : 'GenericCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

[See this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JDXPk/18/)

I dont know if the concept works, or if angular has its own means (which I haven't found yet) or if another, better solution exists. Please write your thoughts, improvements and so on down. This should be the base concept of our big application.

Comment: have you looked at this? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/

Comment: angularUI router is what you want I use it on a very large app with lots of deep linking.... whatever persistent data you want to not lose when controllers are being destroyed needs to be stored in a service.